# GPG - use cached key before prompting for other cards when multiple receivers?

Tags: gnupg, smartcard

When using gpg 2.2.28 & gpg-agent to decrypt a ciphertext that has been encrypted for (any one of) multiple 'receivers', the default behaviour is that it tries to find and use private keys in some deterministic (governed by what, I'm not sure) order.

If the private keys are held on cards, and the public keys are in the local keyring, this means an 'insert card [number]' prompt that must be cancelled before the next key will be tried - even if a later key is already cached from earlier use & pinentry.

Is there a way of changing this behaviour through user configuration? Or by invoking `gpg` differently (that I could propose to `pass`, where this affects me most)?